# Why does addClass() method in jQuery not work if you add a period before the class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner to jQuery and it seems that class names always have a period character when used as an argument to a method.

However, the addClass() method does not work if you add a period to the class name. Why?

Comment: That's how they've written the method.

Comment: can you provide with an example of code you're trying?

Comment: Every API has a design. In this case the designers of jQuery might have thought that adding a period is redundant when the `addClass` method is meant specifically for classes. There can be for example a method which could accept an ID as well as a class, and in that case a period or a hash at the beginning is a convenient way to distinguish between them.

Comment: *"class names always have a period character when used as an argument to a method"* - this is not correct.  A period character at the start indicates that the next string (up to the next special character, space/another period/hash etc) is a class name.  It's not part of the class name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the "class name" and a "selector" are two different things.

As the name implies, `addClass` (and `removeClass`) is just looking for the class name.  So for an element like this:

```
<div class="someName">
```

the class name is just that, "someName".  No period character.

A *selector* is a different thing entirely.  It can contain element names, class names, IDs, and a wide variety of other things.  Selectors are used in many places, such as in defining CSS targets.  Specifically in what you're seeing, they're used by JavaScript functions like `document.querySelector` and by jQuery's `$` function to find elements.

In a selector, the period is a special character indicating that the following text refers to a class name.  The text *itself* is the class name.  They're two different tokens within the selector.

Comment: It may be edifying to note that a class may have a period in it, but it would need to be escaped if used in `addClass` or in `querySelector`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: It can?  I'm now somewhat frightened that I may encounter that in someone's project someday, because that's just asking for confusion :)

Comment: :) Unfortunately, yes. It can also have a `#` so you could end up with a class name of `#id.class` ... BTW, it can also be emoji. So far, I haven't found anyone who's set the ID of their element to , but it's just a matter of time...